# Lambda expression support in Appdynamics 4.2 and 4.3

Tags: jvm, appdynamics

I see that Appdynamics 4.2 claims to [support](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Instrumenting+Java+8+Constructs) Java 8 lambda instrumenting, but this support was [removed](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Monitor+Java+Interface+Static+and+Default+Methods) in 4.3.
I cannot find anything in [4.3 release notes](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Release+Notes) that mentions removing support for lambdas.

What's happened? Is it somehow related to [JDK-8145964](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145964)?

Comment: Perhaps. The [other Java 8 features are still mentioned](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Monitor+Java+Interface+Static+and+Default+Methods). Technically, it would be still be possible to instrument these generated classes, by instrumenting the `LambdaMetaFactory`, intercepting them while they are generated. But it would be a questionable feature, as these classes do not carry the actual semantic; the right approach would be to instrument the actual target method instead.

Answer (score 2):

See [4.3.x Documentation⇒POJO Entry Points⇒Monitor Java Interface Static and Default Methods](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Monitor+Java+Interface+Static+and+Default+Methods):

> Note that another Java language feature introduced in Java 8, lambda method interfaces, are not supported by the AppDynamics Java Agent.

It’s possible that this is due to technical difficulties with [JDK-8145964](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145964) as you suspect. But I’d also point out that this kind of Instrumentation would be questionable. It’s not this JRE generated class that implements any specific behavior, it’s the invoked target method.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Lambda expressions has been in the product since 4.1 which shipped in 2015 I believe. That being said we are always enhancing support. These do have some limitations after initialization of the classes using them (dynamic instrumentation limits). The product should support them, we have added some additional capabilities and features for Lambda expressions in our next major release. Have you tried to contact help @ appdynamics.com

Comment: I haven't tried contacting support yet. I'm just confused because I cannot find any info about removing support for Lambdas in 4.3 release notes, but documentation says that they are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was not mentioned in release notes, but instead [Support Advisory 56039](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PAA/Support+Advisory+56039%3A+Errors+triggered+by+lambda+constructs) was raised. They indeed mention JDK-8145964 as a reason for removing the support.